# При записывании отрицательного числа пишет "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, python-3.x

При записывании отрицательного числа пишет “not all arguments converted during string formatting”

```
import math 
print("y=3,4x^2 при x<0, y=6√x при x>0")
x = float(input("x = "))
if x<0:
     y=3,4*x*x 
elif x==0:
     y=0 
else:
     y=6*math.sqrt(x) 
print('y = %.2f' % y)
```

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве десятичного разделителя нужно использовать точку, а не запятую:

```
y=3.4*x*x
```

Если там стоит запятая, то в `y` сохраняется не одно число, а кортеж из двух чисел - `(3, 4*x*x)`.

---

Подсказка на будущее: если происходит что-то непонятное, то просто выводите на печать содержимое переменных. Например, в этом случае строчка `print (y)` после `if...elif...else` показала бы, что в `y` сохраняется не число, а кортеж.